There's an auto withdraw bot activated in my wallet, how can i get my wallet back?
There's an auto withdraw bot activated in my wallet and all my coins are being transferred out automatically, please does anyone know how i can get my wallet back, i can't even deposit gas fee to claim my Airdrops because the moment i do so it will be transferred out within seconds
